# Angular 5 ngForm: unable to validate select box option on form submission

Tags: angular

I want to validate the select box on `ngForm` submission.
The code is below:

```html
<select name="maincatList"
        id="maincatList"
        [ngModel]="cat"
        #cat_list="ngModel"
        class="form-control"
        required>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option *ngFor="let cat of responseRawCatList" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.categoryName}}</option>
</select>
<div *ngIf="contentStandalonrFrm.submitted && cat.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
  <div *ngIf="cat.errors.required">Field is required</div>
</div>
```

I want that user cannot be able to submit the form without selecting a value in the select box. It should show the validation error.

**Case 1:**
When I submit the button with the `value = ""`, the form is not showing any error and no submission happen.

**Case 2:**
If I select any value and press submit, the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer the `#cat_list="ngModel"` for validation and hence it should be `cat_list` and **not** `cat`..

Change:

```
<div *ngIf="contentStandalonrFrm.submitted && cat.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
  <div *ngIf="cat.errors.required">Field is required</div>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div *ngIf="contentStandalonrFrm.submitted && cat_list.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="cat_list.errors.required" class="text-danger">Field is required</div>
</div>
```

Also try removing the class `class="invalid-feedback"` which also prevents the error message from displaying.. Because it has the css property as `display:none` ..

> [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-template-driven-form-validation-f2xdwk)